# Replace 2D numpy array elements based on 2D indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

This question has probably been asked somewhere before, but I couldn't find any after some search, hence posting here.

Say I have an array `A` and an index array `idx`. Let both the arrays be 2D for the time being.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[3,3,4],
              [4,5,4],
              [3,4,5]])

idx = np.array([[1,1],
                [2,1],
                [1,0],
                [0,0]])
```

Now I want to replace the corresponding elements in `A` based on the indexes in `idx` to `0`.
Basically, I want to do `A[idx]=0`, which doesn't work.

How do I do this efficiently without running a loop?

Preferably, the proposed solution should be scalable to a higher dimensional (3D and above) arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try:

```
A[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]=0
```

output:

```
[[0 3 4]
 [0 0 4]
 [3 0 5]]
```

If you have excessive number of dimensions that you cannot hard code it, you can use:

```
A[tuple(idx.T)]=0
```