# How can I perform the "reverse" of numpy argwhere?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a boolean numpy array, and I perform `np.argwhere()` on it.  Is there any way to easily and efficiently do the reverse operation?  In other words, given the final shape of `a`, and the results of `argwhere()`, how can I find `a`?  I've tried to use the argwhere results together with an array full of False, but can't figure out how to use to do it.  Maybe somehow use `np.where()`?

```
>>> a = np.array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
                  [False, False,  True, False, False]])
>>> results = np.argwhere(a)
>>> results
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int64)
>>> recover_a = np.full(shape=a.shape, fill_value=False)  # I am  
>>> # guessing I could start here then do something...
```

Comment: recover_a[tuple(results.T)] = True?

Comment: @Ali_Sh yes that worked!  If you put this as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Such the answer is proposed by [Ehasn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61491038/13394817) in the duplicated link. Upvote that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `results` columns as indices to update the value in `recover_a`:

```
recover_a[results[:,0], results[:,1]] = True

recover_a
# array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
#        [False, False,  True, False, False]])
```

Comment: This is very useful, but I'm afraid I under-specified the problem.... it needs to scale to arrays of any dimensions, so I can't hard code the number of indexes.... however, this helps my understanding, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
In [233]: a = np.array([[False, True, False, True, False], [False, False, True,
     ...: False, False]])
In [234]: np.argwhere(a)
Out[234]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2]])
In [235]: np.nonzero(a)
Out[235]: (array([0, 0, 1]), array([1, 3, 2]))
```

`argwhere` is just the `np.transpose(np.nonzero(a))`.  One is a tuple of arrays, the other a 2d array with those arrays arranged as columns.

The `nonzero/where` result is better for indexing, since it is a tuple of indices.

```
In [236]: res = np.zeros(a.shape, bool)
In [237]: res[np.nonzero(a)] = True
In [238]: res
Out[238]: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]])

In [239]: a[np.nonzero(a)]
Out[239]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: But if I have no choice and I am starting with argwhere (which is my situation), can I get there?  I tried to use your solution to get me there, but something is not quite right.  I transposed results and then did a_recover[result_T] = True, but got an indexing error.